# 2 divs with flexible height without scrollbars

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, extend

I've been struggling to get my website to have 2 divs which extend to the bottom of the page (to the footer) and without scrollbars. For example: http://hoskyns50.co.uk/about-hoskyns-50th/ I want to remove the scrollbars and make the divs extend the page (just like this website does) with the white background for the content and sidebar divs visible the whole way down the page to the footer.

relevant css:

```
body, html {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    }
body { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    background: #e0d6b6 url(images/bg.png) repeat-x;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    }
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto -30px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.contentwrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    }
#content, #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    }
#content {
    min-width: auto;
    width: auto;
    }
#sidebar {
    margin-left: 2% !important;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    }#footer, #push {
    clear: both;
    }
#footer {
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;    
    border: none;
    background: #808080;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

relevant html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="contentwrapper">
<div id="sidebar">
sidebar
</div><!--sidebar-->
<div id="content">    
content
</div><!--content-->
</div><!--contentwrapper-->
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="footer">
footer
</div> <!--footer-->
</div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At top of CSS use this CSS reset:

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
```

This should be correct:

```
body { 
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    background: #e0d6b6 url(images/bg.png) repeat-x;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
}
body, html {height: 100%; }
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto -30px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.contentwrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    }
#content, #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    }
#content {
    min-width: auto;
    width: auto;
    }
#sidebar {
    margin-left: 2% !important;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    }#footer, #push {
    clear: both;
    }
#footer {
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;    
    border: none;
    background: #808080;
    color: #c4c4c4;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've edited my css to the above but I still see the scrollbar in the content div?? Any other ideas?

http://hoskyns50.co.uk/about-hoskyns-50th/ <- see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

In your css change the:

```
#content, #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    }
```

to:

```
#content, #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    }
```

Note that only the `overflow` value was changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already tried that however I want my visitors to see all of the information on each page. Changing overflow to hidden means that they would not be able to see half of the information on a large page...any other ideas?

Comment: That's because you are setting the `height` to 100%, change it to `auto` in that same section and also in `.contentwrapper` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I've tried that as well, but when I make the height auto, the divs do not stretch to the bottom of the page.

Comment: The answer for what you asked is related to the `overflow` part, but your css has some other flaws though.